# Calling a div class that's set by code behind function in jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have two divs that sit inside a repeater. Basically the div's class names gets set based on what ever my code behind functions return. 
However, I want to be able reference these divs within my javascript which i'm unsure on how to do.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptdivisions" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class='<%# getDivHeaderClass(Eval("Division").ToString())%>'>
                           <%# Eval("Division")%>
                        </div>
                        <div class='<%# getDivMainClass(Eval("Division").ToString())%>'>
                            <br />
                            <dx:ASPxGridView ID="gvrecords" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="gvCentral" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnHtmlDataCellPrepared="gvrecords_HtmlDataCellPrepared">
                                <Columns>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Product Code " VisibleIndex="0" FieldName="code"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Description" VisibleIndex="1" FieldName="description"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Packsize" VisibleIndex="2" FieldName="packSize"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Barcode" VisibleIndex="3" FieldName="barcodeUnit"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Expiry Date" VisibleIndex="4" FieldName="ExpiryDate"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Quantity" VisibleIndex="5" FieldName="packQuantity"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Zone ID" VisibleIndex="6" FieldName="ZoneID"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Location ID" VisibleIndex="7" FieldName="LocationID"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Date Recorded" VisibleIndex="8" FieldName="DateRecorded"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Average WK Sales" VisibleIndex="9" FieldName="AverageWkSales"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                </Columns>
                                <ClientSideEvents EndCallback="function(s, e){Dcs.load()}" />
                                <SettingsText Title="Central" />
                            </dx:ASPxGridView>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Javascript is:

```
    $(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.headerdiv', function () {
            $(".maindiv").toggle("slow");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional class to the div and reference that.

Here is a sample: (the spaces after the class name is important)

```
<div class='<%# "header_class " + getDivHeaderClass(Eval("Division").ToString())%>'>
    <%# Eval("Division")%>
</div>
<div class='<%# "main_class " + getDivMainClass(Eval("Division").ToString())%>'>
```

Then in your js:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.header_class', function () {
        $(this).siblings('.main_class').toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

EDIT:

As the OP commented, this only works if each item in the template is surrounded by a div. If you do not have a div wrapping each item, the following code will work for you:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.header_class', function () {
        $(this).nextAll('.main_class').first().toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Note: I used `$(this).nextAll('.main_class').first().toggle('slow');` as it would be more reliable to the general user. If your divs are always beside each other and no elements in between, you could simply use `$(this).next().toggle('slow');`. If you use the shorter version and end up changing your layout later, it will break.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but perhaps I've not explained myself well. I need the jquery to reference the unique div class name as opposed to just everything. The reason I have a code behind function call in my markup is because i want the class name to be unique. so that when i use my trigger my jquery click, it will only close one div as opposed to every div created by the repeater.

Comment: Any particular reason you want unique classes besides the jQuery selector? The code I provided you does exactly what you want. I'm not sure why you said it will close every div created by the repeater...did you test it? I did: https://jsfiddle.net/eLo4yubh/

Comment: Yes I did test It as you stated in the code, and the result was that it was expanding every div in the repeater. In the jfiddle test you did you have put it in a wrapper div which is the reason your test is working so i'll try that.

Comment: Yep just tried it my end and it works my end. thank you for helping.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize you didn't have a wrapping div. Sorry, I just assumed from habit. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke your function

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.headerdiv', function () {
        $(".maindiv").toggle("slow");
    });
})();
```